# Forest latex how to go to next line in node child

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I am just experiencing with forest, and I'd like to have a responsive child, and not to be in one line as shown in the figure below:

[image]
I'd like to split the text of all child of 1 level. I already tried `QoS Modeling and Analysis\\in 5G Backhaul Networks` and it does not work :/ only when in the next level.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
    \begin{forest}
      % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
      direction switch
      [Service Function Chaining Solutions
        [QoS Modeling and Analysis\\in 5G Backhaul Networks  
          [Thesis\#1
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains]
          ]
        ]
        [SFC avoid overloads
            [Thesis\#2
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Propose architectures\\to classify the solutions]
            [Propose algorithms\\to avoid overloads]
          ]
          [Thesis\#3
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
          ]
        ]
        [SFC avoid overloads in NS
          [Thesis\#4
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
          ]
          [Thesis\#5
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
          ]
        ]
       [Demonstration
          [Implementation
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
    }
\end{figure}
```

I use the following configuration:

```
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\forestset{
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={
      if level=3{}{draw},
      thick,
      edge={thick},
      if level=1{
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-.5em) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        s sep+=.5em,
        for descendants={
          child anchor=west,
          align=left,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          fit=band,
        },
        for tree={
          parent anchor=south west,
          anchor=mid west,
          grow'=0,
          if n children=0{}{
            delay={
              prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
            }
          },
          before computing xy={
            l=2em
          },
        },
        before drawing tree={
          x/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{.6*x()},
          for children={
            x/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1+1em}{.6*x()},
            for children={
              x/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1+2em}{.6*x()},
            }
          }
        }
      }{
        if level=0{
          parent anchor=south,
          anchor=south,
        }{},
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hm, you were very close to what (I guess) you are after -- text in lower nodes are already broken into two lines. On the same way you could do in the second level (or even in the root node) of tree.

Any way, I put some effort to merge and your code fragments in one complete, compilable document (called MWE: Minimal Working Example). At this I rewrite `forest` settings from scratch.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        draw,
        font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
        calign=edge midpoint,
        align=center,
if level =1{draw,
            minimum height=5.6ex,
            edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.south) -- ++ (0,-3mm) -| (.child anchor);}
            }{},
if level>=1{grow'=0,
            folder,
            folder indent=4mm,
            l sep=7mm,
            s sep=1mm}{},
if level =2{draw, align=left}{},
if level>=3{draw=none,
           text width=11em,
           align=left}{},
              }
%
[Service Function %\\ % delete first % to have text in two lines
 Chaining Solutions
    [QoS Modeling and Analysis\\ 
     in 5G Backhaul Networks
        [Thesis\#1
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains]
        ]
    ]
    [SFC avoid\\ overloads
        [Thesis\#2
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Propose architectures\\to classify the solutions]
            [Propose algorithms\\to avoid overloads]
        ]
        [Thesis\#3
           [Study the effect of\\ overloaded links]
        ]
    ]
    [SFC avoid\\ overloads in NS
        [Thesis\#4
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
        [Thesis\#5
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
    [Demonstration
        [Implementation
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you looking for?