# Positioning arrow shape on TikZ forest drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am attempting to adapt a [solution by Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635437/273733) to [Forest latex how to go to next line in node child](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635418/forest-latex-how-to-go-to-next-line-in-node-child) for a report I am writing. I like the `forest` diagram style but I am struggling how to position an arrow underneath the `forest` diagram as `tikz` is new to me. This is how it currently looks (note: I haven't edited the sub-text from the linked question as I am trying to format it first):

[image]

I am not happy with the arrow as it is for two reasons:

1 - My method of positioning the arrow using

```
\node (a) at (1, 0) {};
\node[single arrow,
        draw,
        left color=white,
        right color=black,
        minimum width = 8pt,
        single arrow head extend=6pt,
        minimum height=20cm,
        below=7.5cm,
        at=(a.south),
        ] (b) {\textcolor{white}{\small\textbf{Increasing complexity}}};
```

is making it difficult to position the left-end of the arrow to the to `west` part of the box entitled **Natural evolution** and the right-end of the arrow to the `east` part of the box entitled ***De novo* design**. How can the arrow extend on the x-axis between the `west` of Natural evolution and the `east` of De novo design please?

2 - The method of positioning on the y-axis is also not adequate as I am having to do it manually with the options `below=7.5cm,at=(a.south)` after setting a `\node` at `(1, 0)`. Is there a better way to position it say `10pt` (or any value that can be changed) beneath one of the textboxes (that can be manually changed to the textbox that is the lowest)?

I have been reading about setting positions relative and moving them with constructs such as `\node (node.east) ++(x,y) {}` but would appreciate some advice on the best way to go about this so I can learn from it please.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,shadings}

\newcommand*\Denovo{\textit{De novo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    grow=south,
    font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
    calign=edge midpoint,
    align=center,
    if level=0{%
        draw,,
        font=\bfseries,
        minimum width=18ex,
        minimum height=5.6ex,
        l sep=6mm,
        }{},
    if level =1{%
        draw,
        font=\bfseries,
        minimum width=18ex,
        minimum height=5.6ex,
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.south) -- ++ (0,-3mm) -| (.child anchor);}
        }{},
    if level>=1{%
        grow'=0,
        folder,
        folder indent=4mm,
        l sep=7mm,
        s sep=1mm}{},
    if level =2{%
        draw,
        align=left}{},
    if level>=3{%
        draw=none,
        text width=11em,
        align=left}{},
}
%
[Enzyme design
    [Natural evolution, name=natev
        [Thesis\#1
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains]
        ]
        [Thesis\#2
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains]
        ]
    ]
    [Directed evolution
        [Thesis\#2
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Propose architectures\\to classify the solutions]
            [Propose algorithms\\to avoid overloads]
        ]
        [Thesis\#3
           [Study the effect of\\ overloaded links]
        ]
    ]
    [Rational design
        [Thesis\#4
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
        [Thesis\#5
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
    [\Denovo\ design,name=denovo
        [Implementation
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
]
\node (a) at (1, 0) {};
\node[single arrow,
        draw,
        left color=white,
        right color=black,
        minimum width = 8pt,
        single arrow head extend=6pt,
        minimum height=20cm,
        below=7.5cm,
        at=(a.south),
        ] (b) {\textcolor{white}{\small\textbf{Increasing complexity}}};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, like this:

[image]

Arrow length is calculated as distance between `natev. west` (name of "Natural evolution" node) and `denovo.east` (name of De novo design! node). For positioning at bottom of tree is added to the last node in the first name `natevbottom`:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                shadings, shapes}

\newcommand*\Denovo{\textit{De novo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    grow=south,
    font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
    calign=edge midpoint,
    align=center,
    if level=0{%
        draw,,
        font=\bfseries,
        minimum width=18ex,
        minimum height=5.6ex,
        l sep=6mm,
        }{},
    if level =1{%
        draw,
        font=\bfseries,
        minimum width=18ex,
        minimum height=5.6ex,
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.south) -- ++ (0,-3mm) -| (.child anchor);}
        }{},
    if level>=1{%
        grow'=0,
        folder,
        folder indent=4mm,
        l sep=7mm,
        s sep=1mm}{},
    if level =2{%
        draw,
        align=left}{},
    if level>=3{%
        draw=none,
        text width=11em,
        align=left}{},
}
%
[Enzyme design
    [Natural evolution, name=natev
        [Thesis\#1
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains]
        ]
        [Thesis\#2
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains,
             name=natevbottom]
        ]
    ]
    [Directed evolution
        [Thesis\#2
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Propose architectures\\to classify the solutions]
            [Propose algorithms\\to avoid overloads]
        ]
        [Thesis\#3
           [Study the effect of\\ overloaded links]
        ]
    ]
    [Rational design
        [Thesis\#4
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
        [Thesis\#5
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
    [\Denovo\ design,name=denovo
        [Implementation
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
]
\path   let \p1 = (natev.west),
            \p2 = (denovo.east),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)} in
        node [single arrow, single arrow head extend=6pt,
              draw,
              left color=white,right color=black,
              font=\bfseries, text=white,
              minimum width = 8pt,
              minimum height=\n1,
              below=8pt, right] at (natev.west |- natevbottom.south)    
              {Increasing complexity};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nodes which span over a certain range of can be created with the `fit` library. This example defines two points that are fitted, `(L)` and `(R)`, and then fits the arrow. As illustrated, you can use `xshift` and `yshift` in order to change the location of these points. Notice also that one can use the `text` and `font` keys to control the font of the node.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,shadings,fit}

\newcommand*\Denovo{\textit{De novo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    grow=south,
    font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
    calign=edge midpoint,
    align=center,
    if level=0{%
        draw,,
        font=\bfseries,
        minimum width=18ex,
        minimum height=5.6ex,
        l sep=6mm,
        }{},
    if level =1{%
        draw,
        font=\bfseries,
        minimum width=18ex,
        minimum height=5.6ex,
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.south) -- ++ (0,-3mm) -| (.child anchor);}
        }{},
    if level>=1{%
        grow'=0,
        folder,
        folder indent=4mm,
        l sep=7mm,
        s sep=1mm}{},
    if level =2{%
        draw,
        align=left}{},
    if level>=3{%
        draw=none,
        text width=11em,
        align=left}{},
}
%
[Enzyme design
    [Natural evolution, name=natev
        [Thesis\#1
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains]
        ]
        [Thesis\#2
            [Present multilayer model\\for 4G \& 5G networks]
            [Propose SFC solutions\\ to create service chains]
        ]
    ]
    [Directed evolution
        [Thesis\#2
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Propose architectures\\to classify the solutions]
            [Propose algorithms\\to avoid overloads]
        ]
        [Thesis\#3
           [Study the effect of\\ overloaded links]
        ]
    ]
    [Rational design
        [Thesis\#4
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
        [Thesis\#5
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
    [\Denovo\ design,name=denovo
        [Implementation
            [Study the effect of\\overloaded links]
            [Avoid link congestion\\in network slicing]
        ]
    ]
]
%\node (a) at (1, 0) {};
\path ([yshift=-2em]current bounding box.south west) coordinate (L)
    ([yshift=-2em,xshift=-3em]current bounding box.south east) coordinate (R)
node[single arrow,
        draw,
        fit={(L)(R)},
        left color=white,
        right color=black,
        single arrow head extend=6pt,
        text=white,
        text height=12pt,
        text depth=4pt,
        font=\small\bfseries\sffamily,
        ] (b) {Increasing complexity};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]